# How to resolve ImportError: cannot import name 'PyAsn1UnicodeDecodeError' in ldap3 connection

Tags: python-3.x, ldap3

I am stuck at this error while importing `from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL`.
Please help

Answer (score 3):

Try to update the pyasn1 package

```
pip install -U pyasn1
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled above the same error. In my case my executed python file was named like the ldap3 python library (`ldap3.py`). So i renamed my file and it worked.